# How to wire a duct fan, pressure switch, and fan speed controller

Tags: wiring

My question relates to the wiring sequence with a duct booster fan, pressure switch, and fan speed control. When I draw it out, it seems that black from power source would first go to the P.S, white from P.S. would go to the fan. Black from fan would go to speed control, and white from speed control would go back to power source- all in a circuit with wires meeting in a junction box.  Is this correct or am I way off?

Comment: model numbers?  photos?

Comment: The fan is the load, so it has to be last in the circuit.  Pressure switch, speed control, fan.

Answer (score 1):

Wire to the pressure switch, then to the speed control, then to the motor and back to the junction box.  Just a thought; these small fans make more noise than air. there is usually a better way to get more air into a room.